# Generating multiple APKs in android

Tags: android

I have  one requirement to compress APK size based on type of device(LDPI, MDPI, HDPI.., etc). My client is demanding to give multiple APK's. According to his statement Small devices having low configuration  so the apk size should be less, and MDPI is bit better than LDPI so the size may going to increase. So he is demanding to give the build accordingly. So that user will  download the app with in less time and saves the internal/ External memory.

For that I tried lot of ways to compress the APK, but I failed at every aspect:
*9- Patch : My project does not contains all the images are 9-Patches, in fact 90% of images are non-9patch's.
*Pro-guard:  I tried to reduce the file size using Proguard, but as far as I know proguard is for  protecting the my code, and apk size is not much compressed.
* And I tried out  not working out for me.

- Right now I am following the bellow process, I know this is very bad procedure:
  Generating the APK for LDPI devices I kept all resource files in res/ldpi folder only, I am following with same procedure for MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI Etc.,
- By using current process, I'm wasting lot of time and it is very bad process also I guess.

To solve the above problem can you please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Use Gradle for Android and its support for [APK density splits](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits). Gradle for Android can then generate APK files for each density, plus an optional "fat APK" containing all densities. You can either use Android Studio as your IDE, or set up a `build.gradle` file that can build an existing project in the Eclipse/Ant classic directory structure.

However, your client needs to understand that not all distribution channels support distributing different APK files by screen density. The Play Store does. I do not know about other channels (e.g., Amazon AppStore for Android). And the *user* probably has no idea what the density of their device is, so relying upon the user to choose one of several versions to download from a Web site is unlikely to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Inform your client that for all devices apk size will remain same. Make him/her understand that On play store you do not upload different apk's for different types of devices.

Comment: ,Thanks for quick reply... For few Apps they are mentioning about the app size like varies with device so on..how they are making that ?..